# Action Script 3. Continue animation till last frame without interrupting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, movieclip

I'm creating flash game. Here are 3 different attacks with different animations (keyboard bind z, x, c).

**Problem #1**

For example If I use attack1 (by clicking "z") It shows animation with ~100 frames, but If during animation I clicking attack2 (x) It cancels attack1 animation and start playing attack2 animation. I need to make that when during animation It can't be interrupted by using other animation.

**Problem #2**

If I use attack1 (by clicking "z") and hold "z" animation freezes till I release "z" button. I need to make that If I click any attack button once started play animation and It can't be interrupted/paused by clicking the same button.

In every attack MovieClip in last frame I added code `MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("stay");` that after attack animation played It started playing "stay" animation (this part working).

key_down function:

```
private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 90)
    {
        attack1 = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 88)
    {
        attack2 = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 67)
    {
        attack3 = true;
    }

}
```

key_up function:

```
private function key_up(event:KeyboardEvent)
{

    if (event.keyCode == 90)
    {
        attack1 = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 88)
    {
        attack2 = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 67)
    {
        attack3 = false;
    }
}
```

startAttack() function

```
private function startAttack() {

            if (attack1)
            {
                Hero.gotoAndStop("attack1");
            }
            if (attack2)
            {
                Hero.gotoAndStop("attack2");
            }
            if (attack3)
            {
                Hero.gotoAndStop("attack3");
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code Hero can attack in 3 ways simultaneously, but, as far I understand, you don't want it. So why did you make three separate variables.
Make one and name it 'attack'. Its value will be number of attack type.
You can also create an array that maps attack's number to keycode:

```
var codes:Array = new Array(0, 90, 88, 67);
var attack:Number = 0;
```

and use it in your key_up and key_down functions. Now, you can add new attacks without create additional ifs in functions.

key_down:

```
if(attack > 0) return; // don't interrupt other attack
for(var c in codes) {
  if(codes[c] == event.keyCode) {
      attack = c;
      Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
  }
}
```

key_up:

```
for(var c in codes) {
  if(codes[c] == event.keyCode) {
      if(c == attack) attack = 0;
  }
}
```

startAttack() is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I get errors: 3 errors where `code[1] = 9;....` : `1120: Access of undefined property code.` and other `1120: Access of undefined property codes.` in this line `for(var c in codes) {`

Comment: I don't have Flash right here, so I write a code from my head. Now, it should be better.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for question #2 now It can't be interrupted by clicking the same button, but If during attack1 animation still It interrupts by using attack2 animation. How to fix It?

Comment: I thought that attack-animation lasts while key is pressed. If lasts longer, you should set attack=0; in the last frame of animation instead of key_up function

Answer (score 0):

In startAttack you can check if some attack are in action. You may use state, or check frames to determine can new attack start.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not to get interrupted is to have an identifier if the attack is in motion. In this case, better have a Boolean inAttackMode(or anything) to test and see whether it is. This is based on youe example

```
private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 90)
    {
        attack1 = true;
        inAttackMode = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 88)
    {
        attack2 = true;
        inAttackMode = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 67)
    {
        attack3 = true;
        inAttackMode = true;
    }

}


private function startAttack() {
                if(!inAttackMode){
                if (attack1)
                {
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack1");
                }
                if (attack2)
                {
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack2");
                }
                if (attack3)
                {
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack3");
                }}
    }
```

then put your

```
MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("stay");
    inAttackMode = false;
```

or better yet assign identifiers to each attack like inAttackMode1 is true then other attack can not be played yet.